# How to length levels of non-factor column in R

Tags: r

```
x<- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67)
grp1<-factor(rep(1:2))
grp2<-rep(1:3)
dat <-data.frame(x,grp1,grp2)
```

`length(levels(dat$grp1))` is right, but `length(levels(dat$grp2))` is wrong.

Why?

Comment: `levels` typically takes factor arguments only. `grp2` is an integer variable, so has `NULL` levels. `length(unique(dat$grp2))` works on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are new to R. ***Please read*** [An introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html)

It will give you a good start on the language.

```
x<- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67)
```

OK, you've got a numeric vector

```
grp1<-factor(rep(1:2))
```

`rep` repeats its argument, but since you haven't given a second argument to say how many times to repeat it, `rep(1:2) = 1:2 = c(1, 2)`, so your `rep` doesn't do anything. So now `grp1` is a factor with levels 1 and 2, and values 1 and 2.

```
grp2<-rep(1:3)
```

You've placed the numeric vector `c(1, 2, 3)` in `grp2` (rep is also not needed here).

```
dat <-data.frame(x,grp1,grp2)
```

You bind them into a dataframe.

```
levels(dat$grp1)
[1] "1" "2"
```

Right.

```
levels(dat$grp2)
NULL
```

it's not a factor, so it has no levels. If you want to count the unique values you can use `length(unique(dat$grp2)`.